# How to automatically set focus on a <input> field when it arrives in the viewport after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, viewport, html-input

I know the `autofocus` attribute:

```
<input type="email" id="hello" placeholder="a@b.com" autofocus>
```

to automatically set the focus on a HTML input.

But when the page is much higher than the browser height, is there a way (with a special value of `autofocus`?) to automatically set the focus to a field only when, after scrolling, the `<input>` arrives in the viewport / currently visible part of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function handleScroll() {
    var el = document.getElementById('hello')
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var elemTop = rect.top;
    var elemBottom = rect.bottom;

    // Only completely visible elements return true:
    var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
    // Partially visible elements return true:
    //isVisible = elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;
    if (isVisible) el.focus();
}
```

```html
<body onscroll="handleScroll()" style="overflow: scroll;">
  <input id="hello" type="email" placeholder="a@b.com" style="margin-top: 500px; margin-bottom: 200px;" />
</body>
```

Comment: Good solution indeed! Maybe we can `.blur()` it if it's not visible. Example: you scroll with mouse, you see the input, you scroll below with mouse. Then you can't scroll with keyboard arrows anymore (input out of viewport still has focus).

Comment: Another thing @prime: let's say the input is in the viewport. It has focus. The user is not interested so they click outside of the input to exit focus. Then every small scrolling (even of 1 pixel!) gives focus *again* to the input, it can be annoying for the user! Do you have an idea about this case? "If the input already was in the viewport before, but it doesn't have focus now, it's probably because the user exitted focus, so let's not give the focus again".